# Listen for changes in firestore snapshot with promise

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to understand and fix the code of an angular chat application that should display whether the user has any unread messages on a specific chat.

Whenever the chat gets a new message there is an unread counter that displays how many messages are still unread. However i'm having trouble understanding how `onSnapshot()` and `subscribe()` really work, as i'm using them in some other methods with no trouble.

Here is my code  that loads the user's conversations which has the `unread` counter on it:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.afs
        Promise.all([
            this.getUser2(),
        ]).
        then(
            ([chats2 ]) => {
                this.chats = chats2;
                resolve();
            },
            reject
        )
    });
}
```

And here is my `getUsers2` function located in the same file.

```
getUser2(): Promise<any>
    {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.afs.collection('company')
                    .doc('id')
                    .collection('users', ref => ref.where('id', '==', '5725a6802d10e277a0f35724'))
                    .snapshotChanges()
                    .subscribe((response: any) => {
                        return response.map(a => {
                            const data: Object = a.payload.doc.data();
                            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
                            console.log(data)
                            resolve(data);
                        })


                }, reject);
        });
    }
```

I am not exactly sure why my website is not being updated in real time when i change the `unread` counter value in the db. I assume it has something to be with the first promise method, as i'm not using it in any of the other functions i use to update real time data.